# Facebook Post to fanpage FROM fanpage?

Tags: facebook

So I have the api working where i can get the auth key and post to my Fan Page.

Problem is the post goes up as the my user not as a post from the fan page itself.

```
    $params['message'] = 'Hey this is my new blog post! Head on over to check it out!';
$params['link'] = 'http://link.com';

    $data['returnid'] = $this->facebook->api('/123456789/feed', 'POST', $params);
```

That works fine. But seeing as how I am the owner of the Fanpage it posts with my name and profile pic.
I would like it to post with the name of the fan page and the fanpage pic.

Is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 1):

You need to retrieve a different access token by using `scope=manage_pages`. Then you will be able to post as the administrator of a Facebook Page.

Check out the section **Page Permissions** for retrieving the permissions here:

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/permissions/

and the bottom of this page for posting the actual content:

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/page/

Comment: got ya. the first time my app is installed you have to ok it for manage_pages. What I cant figure out is where to tell it who to post as. I would think it should be one of my $params?

Comment: I have also tried it with the javascript api. But in that I cant tell where to add anything but the message.                                  FB.api('/me/feed', 'post', { message: body }, function(response)

Comment: I see, you might have to add grant_type=client_credentials to the query params when retrieving the access token. Note though that in the above javascript code you trying to post to /me/feed which is your own feed.